# Agora Web SDK not displaying video and audio feed from flutter app

Tags: flutter, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

My project requires video call using flutter (mobile) and native web. When using the temp token generated from the console both web and mobile receive video and audio. When using the token generated from my server the mobile app receives the video feed from the web but the web does get any feed from the mobile app.

However on the app work fine when connecting mobile app to another mobile app.

flutter 2.2
agora_rtc_engine: ^4.0.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed

The problem happens when the UID on the mobile and the web are not the same data type. I was using local storage to save the UID local. The issue with that was it was retrieving the UID as a string not int. Resolved the issue by converting the UID to int when retrieving it from local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Web is not currently supported by agora. There is an alpha release for web support, but since it's not official, it could be buggy.

https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine/versions/4.1.0-alpha.2

Comment: thanks for the response but I am not using flutter web for the web version. I am using the native Web SDK with HTML, CSS and JavaScript